# Linking two HP 2530-48g switches

Tags: switch, sfp

What is the best way to connect two HP 2530-48G (J9775A) switches using the SFP ports? The switches are a few inches apart in the same rack. Is there a SFP direct attach cable?

Comment: The cable required depends on the particular SFPs you are using, and the SFPs must match on each switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the [webpage of accesories for HP 2530-48G (J9775A)](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/networking-switches/product-detail.html?oid=5333809&jumpid=reg_r11944_usen_c-001_title_r0001#!tab=oas) I could not find any Direct Attach Cable for this switch, neither 10G fiber based SFPs.

Among the SFPs compatible with this switch:

- If you want to use the SFP ports for interconection and would
  like/need to avoid optical fiber cables you can use the [HP X121 1G
  SFP RJ45 T Transceiver (J8177C)](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/oas/product-detail.html?oid=3840394) which is 1G and suitable for your
  distance.
- If you don´t have a restriction forcing you to avoid fiber links,
  take into account that [HP X121 1G SFP LC SX Transceiver(J4858C)](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/oas/product-detail.html?oid=3619488)
  is a bit cheaper than the copper one (at least in list price for the
  USA) and also suitable for your distance

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever pair of SFP's you want (SR, LR, T.)

Direct Attach Cables do exist, but I'm only aware of ones for 10/40Gbe -- i.e. SFP**+**.